# GCM message id lifetime?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In GCM, upstream message ids' must [be unique for each message](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#send%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

But it's unclear to me

- whether they need to be unique throughout the lifetime of the app, or
  the lifetime of the message. Specifically, can a message id be reused
  after it's delivered to the application server and the application
  server acked it?
- whether they need to be unique for each client or for all clients?

**EDIT:**

For the downstream messages, [the docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) say that "[message] ID uniquely identifies the message in an XMPP connection" and " be unique (per sender ID)".

So how do these apply for upstream messages?

Comment: "msgId ID of the message. This is generated by the application. It must be unique for each message. This allows error callbacks and debugging." It sure sounds like it has to be unique for *every* message. This is probably due to the fact that sometimes, for certain reasons, messages cannot be delivered. This would be the lifetime of the message. It should not be re-used.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts yea, it is where I quoted

Answer (score 0):

Each message id is unique for each message. So its lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the message. A message id cannot be reused when the message has been successfully delivered.

They even need to be unique for each of the client..